# separate a string

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a file as shown below:

```
Sep     6       18:59   Cash_A2_updates_03_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash_A2_updates_04_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash_A2_updates_05_08_2011.sql
```

The first word in the file name nothing but the schema name. I want to keep it in a separate column and the rest of the file name in the last column as shown below.

```
Sep     6       18:59   Cash A2_updates_03_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash A2_updates_04_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash A2_updates_05_08_2011.sql
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed 's/_/ /'
```

Assuming that's always the first `_` in there.

Answer (score 0):

awk version: (if the file content is like what you shown us)

```
awk 'sub(/_/," ")' yourFile
```

**test**:

```
kent$  echo "Sep     6       18:59   Cash_A2_updates_03_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash_A2_updates_04_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash_A2_updates_05_08_2011.sql"|awk 'sub(/_/," ")'  

output

Sep     6       18:59   Cash A2_updates_03_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash A2_updates_04_08_2011.sql
Sep     6       18:59   Cash A2_updates_05_08_2011.sql
```